# Not getting any response from request in word add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-word, xmlhttprequest, ms-office, word-addins

I have a login form in my word add-in when i submit the form it send the user credentials to sever for authentication, i am using below code to send login request:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
        xhr.open('POST', 'login_api_url', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            if (this.status === 200) {                
               console.log("Success:",this.response);

            } else {
               console.log("Error:",this.response);
            }
        };

        xhr.send("email=email_id&password=******");
```

It is working fine when i send valid user credentials but if i send wrong credentials, request not give any response.

When i send wrong credentials through browser(Firefox), it return below response:

```
"NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - https://login_api_url"
Error: {"status":"error","message":"Unauthorized"}
```

When i run the add-in using visual studio2015 it's working fine with wrong credentials on my local machine but remote add-in not showing any response.

Please help me to resolve it, why the code is working on locally hosted add-in (using visual studio 2015) but for remote add-in it's not giving any response for Unauthorized request.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does the "remote" add-in run? Can the machine where it is running access your service URL? When troubleshooting things like this it is always good to know what HTTP requests/responses are actually sent. You can check that with a tool like Fiddler, for example.

Comment: @Dirk: Thanks for suggestion, I have notice internet explorer response as 'XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.' and stopped at state 3, it is not giving any response in onload.